# How can I simply abbreviate following equation to a sigma sum function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory

When there are $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4$,

how can I simply abbreviate following  equations?

$\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3 + \alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_4 + \alpha_1\alpha_3\alpha_4 +\alpha_2\alpha_3\alpha_4$

and

$\alpha_1\alpha_2 + \alpha_1\alpha_3 + \alpha_1\alpha_4 +\alpha_2\alpha_3+\alpha_2\alpha_4+\alpha_3\alpha_4$

Comment: One way would be to consider a certain subset $P$ of permutations $\sigma: A \rightarrow A$, where $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$. Then, e.g. for the last example you could write $\displaystyle \sum_{\sigma\in P} a_{\sigma(1)}a_{\sigma(2)}$. The set $P$ should be defined such that if $\sigma_1,\sigma_2 \in P$ and $\sigma_1(1)\sigma_1(2)=\sigma_2(1)\sigma_2(2)$, then $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$. For finite sets $A$ it should be easy to count it's elements and generally, characterize it. Though I think it's only worth the hassle if you'll work frequently with this sort of sum, e.g. for a particular problem.

Comment: Maybe use this - https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Cyclic_sum

Comment: I see no equation here.

Comment: As they are elementary symmetric polynomials in $a_1,\dots,\alpha_4$, you might use one of the notations often found for Vieta's relations: $e_3$ and e_2$, or $\sigma_3$ and $\sigma_3$ (indexed by the total degree).